# Can I travel to the UK for leisure holding a UK Business Visa?

Tags: visas, uk

I'm a Kurdish Iraqi national, I have a UK Business Visa valid until 24th Sep 2015. I visited London on 11th May 2015 for some business meetings, and went back to Erbil on 24th May 2015.

I'm planing to travel to Manchester in the next 2 weeks (1st of Sep) to spend 10 days in Manchester as a tourist. Will I be admitted with the the business visa?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. This might be the first question asked by an Iraqi national, and so I extend a special welcome. This question has already been asked and answered, however, at the provided link, with good advice from Gayot Flow.

Comment: "the first question asked by an Iraqi national," Ah? What makes you so sure about this?